# getting full linked list without usage of loop?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

LinkedListA = 3->4->5

LinkedListB = 12->6->9

I am simply trying to add  linkedlistB at the end of the first linkedlistA.
  I am not able to figure out  Why the *final while loop* is able to print 
  the complete linkedlistA WITH all the nodes added from linkedlistB!

```
public static void joinLists(Node headA, Node headB)
{
    Node currentA = headA;
    Node currentB = headB;

    while( currentA.nextLink != null )
    {
        currentA = currentA.nextLink;
    }

    Node newElement = currentB;       
    currentA.nextLink = newElement;      //there is not loop here as you can see to keep updating the list with newElement taking new currentB value    
    currentB = currentB.nextLink;

    currentA = headA;
    while(currentA != null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentA.data);
        currentA = currentA.nextLink;         //output 3->4->5->12->6->9 How!?
    }
}
```

My initial logic was doing simply this:-

```
public static void joinLists(Node headA, Node headB)
{
    Node currentA = headA;
    Node currentB = headB;

    while (currentB != null)
    {
        currentA = head;
        while( currentA.nextLink != null )
        {
            currentA = currentA.nextLink;
        }

        Node newElement = currentB;       
        currentA.nextLink = newElement;      
        currentB = currentB.nextLink;
    }

    currentA = headA;
    while(currentA != null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentA.data);
        currentA = currentA.nextLink;        
    }

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work!

But before that tell me how the first code seems to work?

Comment: You have code that *does* work, and are asking about different code that doesn't work?

Comment: I get it. Thank you. I thought I was supposed to be adding the nodes from second list one by one.

Comment: But as you pointed out in your answer. Making that *one* essential change in one link has now joined LinkedListA and LinkedListB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop appends the list headB at the end of list headA.

```
public static Node joinLists(Node headA, Node headB)
{
    if (headA == null)
    {
        headA = headB;
    }
    else
    {
        Node currentA = headA;
        while (currentA.nextLink != null)
        {
            currentA = currentA.nextLink;
        }
        currentA.nextLink = headB;
    }

    Node current = headA;
    while (current != null)
    {
        System.out.println(current.data);
        current = current.nextLink;
    }

    return headA;
}
```

Then the printing loop would work.

In your second loop you tried something out (`curretnA = head;`).

Less variables will make understanding easier, as shown here.
One must use the return value for the joined list, as headA could be null.

Comment: Sorry That was typo ofcourse, It's currentA = head;

Answer (score 1):

You made the last node in A (the 5) point to the first node in B (the 12), which exactly corresponds to your output.  You don't need a loop because the connections are distributed: each node only knows where the next node is.  In attaching B to the end of A, only 1 link changes: the one you changed.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList Data Structure work by the principal of ValueByReference Logic, that means, each node of linkedList can be stored anywhere in the memory location, we are just linking each node  by mapping memory address to "Node.next" field

In First logic Code

```
    Node newElement = currentB;       
    currentA.nextLink = newElement;        
    currentB = currentB.nextLink;
```

Your directly mapping headB pointer to last element in LinkedListA, so it similar to connecting each node in LinkedList.

Comment: Yup, that clears my concept of linked list completely.